# How to get HttpServletResponse from liferay portal without using PortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse

Tags: java, liferay, endeca

We are using endeca portlet and I want to know how to  get HttpServletResponse from liferay portal action response without using PortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse method.

Comment: please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823 before you crosspost next time. Crossreference: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/72114297

Answer (score 3):

The direct answer to your question is: [Look up how Liferay implements](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/util/PortalImpl.java#L2554) the underlying method. You'll have to duplicate that code - potentially duplicating a few classes that are not available to applications.

The indirect nonanswer is: I doubt that there's anything meaningful that you can do with the HttpServlet*Response* other than messing things up: Liferay might have already written some content to it when you get hold of it. Thus you can't rely on HTTP-headers being included (reproducibly). Heck, you don't even know if your portlet is delivered through Ajax or embedded in the page anyways.

Go with the nonanswer. Unless you come up with a sensible underlying problem, I'd *strongly* advise against doing so (I'd even strongly advise doing so if you'd just used PortalUtil). In most cases that access to HttpServlet*Request* is attempted, it's a hack. On HttpServlet*Response* I can't even come up with something that'd be hackable that way.